# react - how to add multiple lists in options with condition to show one of the lists based on the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to load multiple lists in `options`. I want to show list based on the `country` selected. I can't seem to figure out either.

First I tried to load all the lists and put them in `<option>`

```
# lists 
<datalist id="stockSelection">
{React.Children.toArray(
                EXDATA.map(({ symbol }) => <option value={symbol} />)
              )}
{React.Children.toArray(
                GYDATA.map(({ symbol }) => <option value={symbol} />)
              )}
</datalist>
```

This didn't work. While I see that the list laods, when I try to type anything from `GYDATA` it doesn't show me the options.

## Conditional

{if this.state.country === "United States of America"
{React.Children.toArray(
EXDATA.map(({ symbol }) => )
)}}
else {React.Children.toArray(
GYDATA.map(({ symbol }) => )
)}

```
As expected both are not working, I am trying to figure this out for 2 hours and not making much headway.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<datalist id="stockSelection">
    {this.state.country === "United States of America"
        ? EXDATA.map(({ symbol }) => <option value={symbol} />
        : GYDATA.map(({ symbol }) => <option value={symbol} />}
</datalist>
```

Comment: Thank you. If possible how would I handle multiple countries and different lists? If, else if, and else. Should I be using switch in multiple country scenario?

Comment: make is a separate function.

Comment: <datalist id="stockSelection">{renderList(this.state.country)}
</datalist>